# Excel Data view Eclipse Apache POI

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, apache-poi

My Java program reads an Excel file from a file location and returns the expected result. However, when I move the excel workbook to my Eclipse project under Project Explorer, I am not able to view it in the Excel interface. Upon double clicking I used to see the actual sheet in the Eclipse tab window, but now I see folders and XML files.  The program runs fine when I re-execute without specifying a physical file location. I simply dragged and dropped the Excel workbook from Desktop to my project. I have been working with Excel for a while and have never encountered this issue.  I have updated my Eclipse IDE recently. Not Sure if that was culprit.

Comment: I am confused. Is your problem with eclipse or with your program?

Comment: Eclipse view only. No issue with the program. I am just not seeing the Excel view in the Eclipse window. Due to reputation limits, i cannot attach an Image. Hope this will clears things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the excel file in eclipse, then "open with ..." and chose "System editor" to open your file in Excel:

[image: menu]

Comment: Thanks. I am able to view it now. Any suggestion on whether I should edit Excel docs in the IDE or locally? I usually save it locally and then move the file to the IDE. Want to follow the best practice to avoid file corruption in the future.